# VanillaJS - find middle element in the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a setup like this

```html
    <div class=“container”>
     <div class=“segment segment1”></div>
     <div class=“segment segment2”></div>
     <div class=“segment segment3”></div>
     .
     .
     .
     <div class=“segmentN”></div>
    </div>
```

Where N is an number defined by user so list is dynamical. For container I have applied styles to display it as grid, so EVERY time list has 3 items displayed, list is scrollable. My problem is, how can I via VanillaJS find element which is in the middle of container ? If there are 3 elements in the page, it should select 2nd one, when scrolling down it should select element which is in the middle of container every time to apply some styles to it in addition to grab it’s id. If there are 2 elements, it should select 2nd item as well. I was thinking about checking height of container, divide it by half and checking position of element if it’s in range. So far I was able to write this code in js

```js
function findMiddleSegment() {
    //selecting container
    const segmentListContainer = document.querySelector(`.container`);
    const rect = segmentListContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    //selecting all divs
    const segments = document.querySelectorAll(`.segment`);
    segments.forEach( (segment) => {
        const location = segment.getBoundingClientRect();
        if( (location.top >= rect.height / 2) ){
            segment.classList.add(`midsegment`);
        } else {
            segment.classList.remove(`midsegment`);
        }        
    });
}
```

But it doesn’t work. It finds element in the middle as should, but also applies style for every other element beneath middle segment. I’ve read some answers on stackoverflow, but couldn’t find any idea how to solve my problem.

***EDIT***
In addition to my problem I add additional function to show how I invoke it.

```js
function handleDOMChange() {
    findMiddleSegment(); //for "first run" when doc is loaded

    const segmentListContainer = document.querySelector(`.container`);
    segmentListContainer.addEventListener('scroll', findMiddleSegment);
}
```

Comment: When this runs is there a possibility of more than one midsegment?  Couldn't you just count the segments then place it by dividing the number in half?  To answer the question though. location.top >= rect.height / 2 would add the class to both the mid section and everything under that because anything GREATER THAN or equal to that value would receive the class.

Comment: Hey @KJEK-Code thanks for answering. What do you mean by counting the segments then place it by dividing the number in half? You mean counting all segment, then divide and add styles for result? Is there any way to add more boundary to my if statement so it only applies new style for middle segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very easy way to do it is using the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul'),
      idDisplay = document.querySelector('p b');
      
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  highlightMid,
  {
    root: list,
    rootMargin: "-33.33% 0%",
    threshold: .5
  }
);

function makeList() {
  list.innerHTML = '';
  observer.disconnect();

  const N = document.querySelector('input').value;
  for (let i = 0; i < N;) {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.id = `i_${++i}`;
    item.textContent = `Item #${i}`;
    list.append(item);
    observer.observe(item);
  }
};

function highlightMid(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    entry.target.classList
      .toggle('active', entry.isIntersecting);
  })
  const active = list.querySelector('.active');
  if (active) idDisplay.textContent = '#' + active.id;
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 33.33%;
  padding: .3em 1em;
  list-style: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

.active {
  background: #6af;
}
```

```html
<i>Make a list of:</i>
<input type="number" min="2" placeholder="number of items">
<button onclick="makeList()">make</button>
<p>Active id is <b>yet to set</b></p>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you save my life and my sanity. When I implemented it on my project, it also keeps element above highlighted for some time, here is how I've done it - https://jsfiddle.net/0y8tLjeg/ any idea why it may happen like that ?

Comment: @Marcin, your jsfiddle lacks HTML and CSS which are significant parts of the whole thing. Basically, you need to pay attention to container and items heights, and rootMargin and threshold options. So that you can find what is intersecting and highlighting.

Comment: Okay, i'll play with it and find it out. I make grid in my list, and all rows are "1fr" of height so maybe I should manipulate value in rootMargin

Comment: I've found the problem - I have to make sure that everytime user scrolls, container "jumps to" next row instead of slowly "loading" whatever isn't in viewport if you know what i mean :)

Comment: Yep, so I've found the solution.  rootMargin: "-50% 0%",
    threshold: 1

Comment: @Marcin, great job, congrats!

Comment: All thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If container has only a list of segments inside, it's easer to count the element's children and find the mid element.

```
const segmentListContainer = document.querySelector(`.segmentListContainer`);
const midSegmentIndex = Math.floor(segmentListContainer.children.length / 2) - 1;
let midSegment = segmentListContaner.children[midSegmentIndex];

midSegment.classList.add('midsegment');
```

P.S.

The reason why your code adds 'mdsegment' to each element's class name after the real midsegment element is because of this conditional statement line you wrote.

```
if(location.top >= rect.height / 2){
    segment.classList.add(`midsegment`);
}
```

Comment: @Marcin I like answer better than mine.  You add the -1 to combat the 0 index Kouta?

Comment: Yes, length shows a number of elements. When the length is 3, a list of indexes are 0 ~ 2.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Hey @KoutaNakano thanks for answer. Unfortunatelly you didn't understand my problem. I don't want to just find mid segment of whole list. I want to find mid segment in displayed list. List is scrollable, so everytime user scrolls down I want to find "current" mid segment

Comment: oh I see. good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this. You can use Math.round, Math.ceil or Math.floor like I did.  This works because querySelectorAll returns an array and you can use array.length to count the total number of items in the array then use a for loop to loop over all the segments and place the class based on the Math.(round, floor or ceil) based on your needs.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const segments = container.querySelectorAll(".segment");
const middleSegment = Math.floor(segments.length / 2);
for (let index = 0; index < segments.length; index++) {
    segments[middleSegment].classList.add("middle-segment");
}
```

```css
.middle-segment{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need javascript for this. CSS will do

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
}

.container .segment {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  color: silver;
}

.segment:nth-child(3n-1) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
  <div class="segment">segment</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @code_monk, thanks for answer. Your solution isn't good, despite adding CSS I want to find ID of segment which is currently in the middle of container ( when user scrolls list down )

Comment: There is no ID on a div that looks like `<div class=“segment3”></div>`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can find id in array based on which div was found doing myArray.findIndex( segment => segment===foundSegment )

Comment: That's is not an id in the way the DOM knows it. That's an index

Comment: Yes, but it's an index which I need to find to display for user so css selector n-th child won't work